# Sing in on twitter via Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter, authentication

I'm using PHP Framework Codeigniter.
I need help to implement twitter login on my website.

Every solution what I find until now is deprecated.

If someone know some useful post, library, tutorial it will be helpful.

Version of Codeigniter is 3.0, but I guess if someone have solution for older one it should work on this one too.

Comment: Have you tried A3M? https://github.com/donjakobo/A3M

Comment: Thank you Craig,

A3M have Detail information about implement 
Facebook,
Twitter,
Yahoo,
Google features.

If is work for Codeigniter 2.0, it should be fine for 3.0